# Menu not displaying in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, navigation, menu

top navigation menu not displaying in my magento. I refreshed cache and made reindexation. I followed many links and made all the possible options provided from the links. Still it's not showing menu.

Comment: Have you assign root category to your store?

Comment: ya. I assigned.

Comment: Are all the categories you created, are the sub-categories of root?

Comment: I created correctly.

Comment: Did you set your categories as active in menu? are you sure about your template? maybe you use mega menu in your store?!

Comment: I am not using mega menu

Comment: Try to enable the template path hints and find which block class is your menu using.

Comment: I enabled and i able to see all the paths except top menu

Comment: Go for a fresh install, then include your custom extensions and theme used one by one

Comment: It's not possible now.Do you know what are all the code files we have to check for top menu.

Comment: Its basically the navigation but if you have any category extension or menu extension it may have been rewritten by extension, just try to uninstall extension one by one, or simply changing theme to default to check if its the bug in theme

Comment: Yaa correct. It is overwritten by one extension. I removed that extension. Now it's working fine. Thank u...

Comment: Good to know it worked, just posted it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the below rewrite code in one extension,

```
     <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <navigation>Modulename_Block_NavigationTop</navigation>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
    <page>
        <rewrite>
            <html_topmenu>Modulename_Block_NavigationTop</html_topmenu>
        </rewrite>
    </page>
```

I removed the extension, now it's working correctly.

Comment: A theme I downloaded a while ago caused the same error. Thanks for pointing out. After removing it, the menu came back.

Comment: Could you please share how did you know that what caused the issue. Wha search techniques did you use. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have any category extension or menu extension it may have been rewritten by extension, just try to uninstall extension one by one, or simply changing theme to default to check if its the bug in theme

Answer (score 1):

Can't use comment due to reputation sadly...

But, have you set the category's on "active" and (more important) on "include in Navigation Menu*"?

Comment: I set category's on active. include in Navigation Menu also enabled.

Comment: Does the menu work when you use the Magento default template?

Comment: menu not work works even using default template

Comment: Not really clear: it is not working in the default template?

Answer (score 1):

I found an option:

System > Configuration > Category > Category top navigation > Enable Mega Menu

By default this option is set to 'yes' and apparently requires a (mega menu) plug-in to display the top level menu. Setting this option to 'no' generates standard HTML UL/LI code which can then be picked up by a framework like bootstrap to display a top level menu. This of course requires that you rewrite the code in topmenu.phtml for your template allowing it to be specified in the desired format.